# Generic syntax for extends or equal to

Tags: java, generics

How is the syntax in Java for GenericExample<*ItemType (extends or equal to) Object*>?

Thanks,
Adam.

**Update:**

Thanks for all your replies.
The answers here are more related to the use of the generics in code, I would like to discuss the deceleration implementation, for example:

```
class GenericExample<ItemType (extends or equal to) ParentType> {
}

class Inherited<ParentType> extends GenericExample<ParentType> {
    /* The type parameter in this class does not compile.
       I would like to find a work around to make something like this to work. 
       I would like to have ParentType=JComponent , and thus to specify that the  
       Inherited class uses JComponent for needed flexibility*/
}
```

I hope this makes more sense...

Adam.

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure that it's not possible in Java. If I understood it correctly, it's like when you in C# declare a "GenericExample< T > where T: SomeParentClass"

Comment: @djechelon: You would be wrong in thinking that it isn't possible. =)

Comment: I never use a single letter to refer to a parameter type, I always use a mining-full Type name, it makes it easier to keep track over what the object needs to do, or what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already got it:

```
GenericExample<ItemType extends MyObject>
```

A first guide on generics can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html

Comment: shouldn't that at least include a Generic parameter? Like: GenericExample<T extends MyObject> . Still bumping, as I think you have provided what the OP needed.

Comment: ItemType is a generic parameter. But you are right, in Java, common usage is to use One letter (ususally T) for generic parameter.

Comment: Also remember that this is only enforced at compile time and will be replaced with type casts at runtime due to type erasure in Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
GenericExample<T extends Object>
```

Comment: You are correct here, but I think it's more clear if you use some type other than `Object` as the type bound, since what you show here is equivalent to just `GenericExample<T>`.