# Java List<Parent> and List<Children> method

Tags: java, list

Suppose we have the following:

```
public class Parent{
     public void setXXX(String XXX);
     public String getXXX();
}

public class Children extends Parent{
 ....
}
```

Now I want to create a method called clone List like the following:

```
public List<Something> cloneList(List<Something> original){
    List<Something> newList=new ArrayList<>();
    for(Something e:original){
        Something newE=new Something();
        newE.setXXX(e.getXXX());
        newList.add(newE);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

The thing is we want cloneList can be applied to both `List<Parent>` and `List<Children>`, so is there anyway that applicable for "Something"?

Something cannot be "? extends Parent" or "Parent" due to the Java `Collection<Parent>` incompatible with `Collection<Children>`

Assumption:
1. Don't want to use any serialization approach or reflection.

2. We are unable to modify the Parent and Children class. This is predefined in 3rd party Jar.
3. SuperParent class is not possible because we cannot modify Parent as stated in 2.

Comment: Consider the fact that you cannot post < > brackets in your question unless you format it as code.

Comment: There is no solution that meets all the constraints you have added.  To create a faithful copy of an object whose class is not statically known, you need to use either reflection or a method that is statically known to be available.  If a copy method were already available on these classes then surely you would be using it in your sample code.  (Note that `Object.clone()` could possibly serve that purpose, but only if class `Parent` implements `Cloneable`.  Even if it does, `Object.clone()` can be very problematic.)

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible in Java. Take a look at [Generic syntax for extends or equal to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737613/generic-syntax-for-extends-or-equal-to).

You could change your method as follows and make your Parent class extend SuperParent.

```
public static <T extends SuperParent> List<T> cloneList(List<T> original, Class<T> type) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    List<T> newList=new ArrayList<>();
    for(T e : original){
        T x = type.newInstance();
        x.setXXX(e.getXXX());
        newList.add(x);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Also, you could choose another cloning approach. For example, using Apache Commons' `SerializationUtils`:

```
List<Children> result =  (List<Children>) SerializationUtils.clone(originalList);
```

Comment: I'd agree more with the advice on Serialization (or the dreaded `clone`, but forget I just said that), than with the reflection-based suggestion. First, it assumes the existence of a parameterless constructor. Second, the new copies, while they will have the correct type, will not have the full internal state of the originals, which is why serialization would be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use generics this way, only reflection.

For a type variable `T`, you cannot use `new T()`. That's because generics are a compile-time mechanism, and `new` is used in run-time to create a specific-type object, and the compiler cannot create the appropriate reference to the type at compile time. So while this:

```
new ArrayList<T>();
```

is legal, because the compiler actually compiles it into the code for creating the raw `ArrayList` type, this:

```
new T();
```

is not, because the compiler does not even know what the actual class will be (even if it was just defined as `T extends Parents` it could be a class that has not even been written when the program compiled, like `Grandchildren` or something), and does not even know if it has a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In a general sense, you should be able to use a method having this signature:

```
public <T extends Parent> List<T> cloneList(List<T> original)
```

That's not your biggest problem, however.  THAT would be obtaining copies of the list elements.  Your code cannot use

```
T newE = new T();  // doesn't work
```

because the existence of a nullary constructor for type argument T cannot be guaranteed.  Instead, you need a method that will return a correctly-typed copy.  You cannot do this with complete type safety, but you can come close.  You can implement these methods:

```
public Parent Parent.copy();
public Children Children.copy();
```

... in whatever way is appropriate, and then write your method like so:

```
public <T extends Parent> List<T> cloneList(List<T> original) {
    List<T> newList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (T originalItem : original) {
        newList.add(original.getClass().cast(original.copy()));
    }

    return newList;
}
```

(Note that although the documented return type of `Object.getClass()` is `Class<?>`, which would not work for this purpose, the [method documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) says that the return type is actually a bit more specific than that, enough so to make this work.)

Comment: `new T();` cannot be used not just because of the nullary constructor, but also because you cannot instantiate a type variable. But more importantly, the `copy()` method may not be able to copy the internal state properly if there are any final fields in the class. A copy constructor would be needed, and then you'll need to use `getConstructor(...)` for this.

Comment: @RealSkeptic the `copy()` method I proposed is not copying state from one object to another, it is returning a copy of the object on which it is invoked.  It can do that any way it needs to do, including invoking a copy constructor.  It does not need to use reflection because it is an instance method of the object's class, hence it knows what constructor to use, and how, to instantiate an object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of `cloneList` to:

```
public <X extends Parent> List<X> cloneList(final List<X> original)
```

Then it will work, at least for the method signature. You can internally construct a `List<Parent>` and then cast it to `List<X>` and ignore the warnings if you need to; there's no way to find out the runtime type of "X".